# Dealing with 404s from ms sharepoint extension (/_vti_bin/owssrv.dll and /MSOffice/cltreq.asp )

Tags: apache-2.2, sharepoint, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

The MS sharepoint extention requests the following files:

/_vti_bin/owssrv.dll

and

/MSOffice/cltreq.asp

These requests can generate a lot of 404s which make log files harder to read. I have been redirecting these to / so they don't show up on the error log. Is redirecting to a different file the best way to handle these 404s or could that cause problems with the sharepoint extension? Is there a way to simply ignore and not log these 404s using .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this blog entry](http://mark.kolich.com/2009/06/howto-apache-dont-log-yourself-dont-log-specific-ip-address.html) that talks about how to not log certain requests in Apache.